# Implementing ORDER BY on a Simple DBMS in Java

Tags: java, database, sorting

I´m implementing a simple single-user DBMS and I have to be able to have an ORDER BY instruction.

The idea is that I can create a table with any number of columns and have an algorithm that sorts the table given a specific number of columns and the ordering( Ascending or descending) of each column.

Here are the basic classes I have:

```
public class Column{
    final static INT=0;
    final static CHAR =1;
    final static BOOLEAN =2;
    int ColType;

}

public class Table{
    ArrayList<Column> columns;
    ArrayList<Tuple> tuples;


}

public class Tuple{
    Table table;//The table to which the tuple belongs to. This gives us the columns types required in the tuple
    ArrayList<Object> vals;

}
```

Is there any existing algorithm  to accomplish this or any guidelines you could give me to solve this problem?

What I would like to be able to do is to have a method `sortTableBy(ArrayList<Column> n`) that takes the columns I give it as parameters to order the table.

For example if I have

```
Table: Student
SName   |  sGPA   | sCollege
Maria      4.5         Harvard
Brand      4.5         UFB
John       3           UCLA
Wislon     2           Berkley
```

If I call `sortTableBy([sName,sGPA])`
It would yield

```
Table: Student
SName   |  sGPA   | sCollege
Brand      4.5         UFB
John       3           UCLA
Maria      4.5         Harvard
Wislon     2           Berkley
```

calling `sortTableBy([sGPA,sName])`

```
Table: Student
SName   |  sGPA   | sCollege
Wislon     2           Berkley
John       3           UCLA
Brand      4.5         UFB
Maria      4.5         Harvard
```

and calling `sortTableBy([sGPA,SCollege])`

```
Table: Student
SName   |  sGPA   | sCollege
Wislon     2           Berkley
John       3           UCLA
Maria      4.5         Harvard
Brand      4.5         UFB
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a `comparer` per column (*columns in order criteria*), with `Java 8 Stream`  you can do this:

```
Comparator<Table> byColumn0 = (t1, t2) -> t1.columns.get(0).compareTo(t2.columns.get(0));

Comparator<Table> byColumn1 = (t1, t2) -> t1.columns.get(1).compareTo(t2.columns.get(1));

tables.stream().sorted(byColumn0.thenComparing(byColumn1));
```